# How do I handle bitfields and qsorting together?

Tags: c, bit-fields, qsort

The language is C.
Recently here I asked for and received help making the function qsort work for an array of structures.

I am now studying bit-fields and trying to make a program that uses a structure that uses another structure using bitfields and then sorting it out. But when I compile it, I get error at the compare function that "dereferencing pointer to incomplete type" and I had many trials again but still can't make it work. Can you folks help me?

Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int compare(const void * a, const void * b)
{
    struct emp *orderA = (struct emp *)a;
    struct emp *orderB = (struct emp *)b;

    return (orderA->d.year - orderB->d.year);
}

int main()
{
    int i;
    struct date{
        unsigned day : 5;
        unsigned month : 4;
        unsigned year : 12;
    };

    struct emp {
        char name[10];
        struct date d;
    };

    struct emp e[5];
    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        scanf("%s %d %d %d", e[i].name, e[i].d.day, e[i].d.month, e[i].d.year);
    }
    qsort(e, 5, sizeof(struct emp), compare);

    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        printf("%s %d %d %d\n", e[i].name, e[i].d.day, e[i].d.month, e[i].d.year);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In the `compare` function this line`return (  orderA->d.year -orderB->d.year  );` knows nothing about the `struct` fields (in your posted code), or even what `struct emp` means.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Why this doesn't work

Since you've defined `struct emp` inside your `main` function, it only exists inside your `main` function.

As such, when you attempt to cast to `struct emp*` in your `compare` function, the type does not exist.

If you want this code to work, you should move

```
struct emp {
    char name[10];
    struct date d;
};
```

out of your main function and above your compare function.

Ideally you should move it into its own header file and include that.

The same applies to your `struct date` since it is used inside `struct emp`. So move

```
struct date{
    unsigned day : 5;
    unsigned month : 4;
    unsigned year : 12;
};
```

out of your `main` function as well.

---

## Scopes in C

Keep in mind as a general rule in C that any non-static identifier declared or defined inside a scope (meaning between a set of `{}`) is local to that scope and cannot be accessed outside of that scope.

Comment: You should do the same with `struct date`.

Comment: Good point, didn't mention it due to it being unused in the sample code.

Comment: It is part of `struct emp` as your answer has too. It is used in the `compare` function.

Comment: Thank you. How silly of me. But now that I have moved both the structs out, I am getting a segmentation error at runtime. Do you know what the reason could be?

Comment: That could happen if you input a name longer than 9 characters I guess. You should create another question showing your updated code and mentioning the `segmentation fault`

Comment: *anything declared or defined inside a scope (meaning between a set of {}) is local to that scope and is `no longer declared/defined when you leave that scope.`* This is not correct.

Comment: Is the claim incorrect or the terminology? I'm curious about this, please elaborate

Comment: That is only true for objects with automatic storage duration.

Comment: If you are referring to `malloc`'d pointers, the actual variable containing the pointer is also destroyed when leaving the scope, the memory is still allocated and the data is not overwritten, but the variable is indeed no longer defined. If I still misunderstand you, let's move this to chat and talk more about it.

Comment: Objects aren't destroyed in C. Their lifetime simply ends. I'm talking about storage durations other than automatic. Those storage durations do not end when execution leaves the scope.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124158/discussion-between-sokkyoku-and-2501).